# How do I profile memory usage for .net core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am seeing what looks like to be a memory leak with using streams for file downloads in a .NET Core + ASP.Net Core application.

I want to track down what exactly is causing this issue and the only thing that I have run across so far is dotMemory from JetBrains. Is there anything else / free that I can use to start diagnosing the issue?